# Twilio flex UI get worker attributes and show sideNav button to admin only

Tags: reactjs, plugins, twilio, worker, twilio-flex

I am building a custom twilio flex react-plugin.
I am trying to add an custom view with a sidenav button.So the button should be visible for admin only.
I am trying to access current worker attribute and check if the role includes "admin".

```
init(flex, manager) {
    // adds the sms button to the navbar
    flex.SideNav.Content.add(<customButton key="nav-custom-button"/>,
    {
      sortOrder: 1,
      if: (props) => props.worker.attributes.roles.includes( 'admin'),
    });
```

But the flex local instance can not load and trying to authenticate repeatedly.

I have also tried

```
if( manager.worker.attributes.roles.includes( 'admin')){
    flex.SideNav.Content.add(<OutboundSmsButton key="nav-outbound-sms-button"/>);
     }
```

It logs error in console can not read property attributes of undefined.

Whats the right way to fetch worker(for current agent)attributes in a twilio react plugins?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be as below:

```
if( manager.workClient.attributes.roles.includes( 'admin')){
    flex.SideNav.Content.add(<OutboundSmsButton key="nav-outbound-sms-button"/>);
     }
```

or if its not inside init(flex,manager), it will be needed to import flex
like below:

```
import * as Flex from '@twilio/flex-ui';


 let mgr = Flex.Manager.getInstance()
     let roleName = mgr.workerClient.attributes.roles
    if( roleName.includes( 'admin')){
          flex.SideNav.Content.add(<OutboundSmsButton key="nav-outbound-sms-button"/>);
       }
```

source:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/manager
https://twilio.github.io/twilio-taskrouter.js/Worker.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the worker attributes inside **init()**:

```
init(flex, manager) {
   const workerAttributes = manager.workerClient.attributes;
   const isAdmin = workerAttributes.roles.includes('admin');
   ...
}
```

To get the worker attributes anywhere else:

```
import { Manager } from '@twilio/flex-ui';

const store = Manager.getInstance().store;
const workerAttributes = store.getState().flex.worker.worker.attributes;
const isAdmin = workerAttributes.roles.includes('admin');
...
```